# How to use function to pointer in quick sort algorithm

Tags: c++, quicksort

I use function to pointer to determine how to arrange an array by quick sort algorithm. But I don't know how to call function to pointer in recursive

cannot call function "compare"

```
void quickSort(int arr[], int left, int right, bool *(compare)(int , int )) {
  int i = left, j = right;
  int tmp;
  int pivot = arr[(left + right) / 2];

  while (i <= j) {
        while (arr[i] < pivot)
              i++;

        while (arr[j] > pivot)
              j--;

        if (compare(i,j)) {
              tmp = arr[i];
              arr[i] = arr[j];
              arr[j] = tmp;
              i++;
              j--;
        }
  }

  if (left < j)
        quickSort(arr, left, j, asc);   

  if (i < right)
        quickSort(arr, i, right, asc);
}
```

Comment: Are you saying the compiler generates some sort of complaint for  "if (compare(i,j)) { ... }" ?   Or is the result incorrect?  You need to describe the error message or result error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solution

```
int Partition (int test[], int low, int high,bool(*comparisonFcn)(int, int))  
{  
int pivot = test[high];   
int i = (low - 1); 

for (int j = low; j <= high - 1; j++)  
{  

    if (comparisonFcn(pivot,test[j]))  
    {  
        i++; 
        swap(test[i], test[j]);  
    }  
}  
    swap(test[i + 1], test[high]);  
    return (i + 1);  
}  

void QuickSortASC(int test[], int low, int high)  
{  
    if (low < high)  
    {  
        int pi = Partition(test, low, high, asc);  
        QuickSort(test, low, pi - 1);  
        QuickSort(test, pi + 1, high);  
    }  
}  
void QuickSortDES(int test[], int low, int high)  
{  
    if (low < high)  
    {  
        int pi = Partition(test, low, high,des);  
        QuickSort1(test, low, pi - 1);  
        QuickSort1(test, pi + 1, high);  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> cannot call function "compare"

Why? Seems to compile:

```
void quickSort(int arr[], int left, int right, bool *(compare)(int , int )) {
  int i = left, j = right;
  int tmp;
  int pivot = arr[(left + right) / 2];

  while (i <= j) {
        while (arr[i] < pivot)
              i++;

        while (arr[j] > pivot)
              j--;

        if (compare(i,j)) {
              tmp = arr[i];
              arr[i] = arr[j];
              arr[j] = tmp;
              i++;
              j--;
        }
  }

  if (left < j)
        quickSort(arr, left, j, compare);   

  if (i < right)
        quickSort(arr, i, right, compare);
}
```

Comment: I use compare to determine how to sort up ascending or descending.